# How to exchange data between an ASP.NET WebSite and another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

In my solution there are two projects:

- ASP.NET Web Forms Site
- WPF application

The WPF application handles the local GUI and has a C# engine to do the logic stuff (i.e. database, low-level I/O, etc..). The web site of course provide a remote access to some other functionalities.

What's the best way to exchange data between them?
I need to use a standard IPC or due to they are in the same .NET solution there is something easier? I.e. a shared class

Comment: `I.e. a shared class` - I would assume if you intent to share common classes that those would end up in a logical, separate DLL, i.e: `Common.dll` you could then reference.

Comment: Would this be better than a IPC?

Comment: @Mark Depends on usage and problem.

Comment: I just want to retrieve the fields of a submitted form from the WPF application and sent back an answer to the web site cs code.